# How to duplicate the recent written word in vim

Tags: vim

If I just type the word **car**, how can I do to write it one more time by using normal mode?, I just spect **carcar**.

If I do `yyp`, Vim copy the current line in a bottom line, but I need the word in the same line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know you want repetition *before* the insert, you can supply a `[count]` to the `i` / `a` commands. For example, `2icar<Esc>` yields `carcar`.

Comment: This is especially a nice trick when you want to create a comment bar of defined length. A simple `100i/<esc>` will create a bar of 100 slashes.

Answer (score 5):

Use `.` to repeat whatever you did last.

Comment: This *almost* works in vim. I was testing the same theory. When you type in `iasdf esc .` you get `asdasdff` as the input is one char off.

Comment: Good point! Have to be sure what you are repeating is what you want to repeat.

Comment: Best vim tip ever.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on the c in car you can type

```
ywep
```

to yank the word (`yw`), move to the end of the word (`e`) and then paste the word (`p`).

If you are anywhere in car you can use `yiw` to yank inner word to copy all of car. So

```
yiwep
```

will duplicate car.

Answer (score 2):

As @kid writes in his answer, `.` will repeat the insert, but you have to `a`ppend (or move the cursor beyond the last character first).

An alternative is `a<C-@>`; the latter command inserts the last inserted text again in insert mode; cp. `:help i_CTRL-@`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar thing works with visual mode, <kbd>viw</kbd> will select the current/inner word, then you may copy/yank it (<kbd>y</kbd>) and paste it (<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>$p</kbd>).

You may add the following lines to vimrc:

```
map <A-v> viw"+gPb
map <A-c> viw"+y
map <A-x> viw"+x
```

These bindings follow the Windows-style keys of <kbd>Control+V</kbd>, <kbd>Control+C</kbd> and <kbd>Control+X</kbd>; except using <kbd>Alt</kbd> instead of <kbd>Control</kbd>. Adjust to your preference.

See:

- [Word-wise cut, copy and paste](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip834)